# Hide/ Show list item based on Intranet, Extranet Zone

Tags: list, web-application-zones

Is there anyway to hide an item in a SharePoint list based on whether the user has accessed the site from an internal URL as opposed to an external?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, presuming you're using Windows Integrated Authentication for internal access and Forms Based Authentication for the extended extranet zone...

The list item (or the list, or in fact the site that the list is on) can be assigned unique permissions, and you can then simply assign permissions to a group that contains the user's regular Active Directory account.

Meanwhile, the group that contains their unique FBA user name can be excluded from the item/list.

Comment: Thanks Brian, unfortunately we are using the AD login for both. If we were to add FBA that sounds like we would have to administer 2 different sets of permissions. Is this the usual practice?